# URL created by pushstate of History object

Tags: javascript, html, url-rewriting, pushstate, history.js

I am learning how to cange my URL to show query string parameters sent to server

I am taking some data from user, making an ajax call to server, when server returns data i show that to user,,, So, if my URL earlier was abc.com . and If I use pushstate to append query string parameters to URL i.e. to make it abc.com?param1=val1&param2=val2  ,

Would this new URL be the actual URL for those 2 parameters taken from user. I mean If I copy and send this link to somebody : abc.com?param1=val1&param2=val2

would it open that abc.com  to show data results for these two parameters?

Thanks in advance`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

It does not get the data for for `abc.com?param1=val1&param2=val2` but instead gets data for `abc.com`, the default

But you can fix this either using JS or Server-side prog lang.

1. If you're using JavaScript, you can do it by parsing `document.URL` yourself and then load the data based on the params. (Not recommended)
2. Else if on the server, directly serve the content for `abc.com?param1=val1&param2=val2`

The second method is highly recommended.

Comment: BUt the request to server is going when the user enters data and clicks on Go. If I will send this link to somebody, how would the request go to server without clicking Go. If I do server side programming , and server should directly serve content for abc.com?param1=val1&param2=val2  , how should I call servlet w/o clicking Go, because that should be done iff the URL already has those parameters.

Comment: Then you'll have to use the first method. 
When the page finishes loading, check if there are any params passed to the URL, parse them (there are several libraries which will help you out with this: such as [this](http://davisjs.com/)) and serve content the same way you do when user enters data and clicks the go button.

Remember that the only difference between doing it on clicking go and on page load is that in the first approach you are getting the data from the user and in the second, you get the data directly from URL.